# fastest way to pass data inside process using zeromq

Tags: zeromq

Writing my first zeromq application so sorry about simple question.
In my financial software I receive quotes from stock exchange. Each update looks like that:

```
struct OrderUpdate {
    uint32_t instrumentId;
    uint32_t MDEntryID;
    uint32_t MDUpdateAction;      // 0 - New 1 - Change 2 -Delete
    double /*decimal*/ MDEntryPx;
    double /*decimal*/ MDEntrySize;
    uint32_t RptSeq;
    uint32_t MDEntryTime;
    uint32_t OrigTime;
    char MDEntryType;
};
```

I do not allocate this structures at runtime, instead i pre-allocate and then reuse (reconfigure) them.

I need to pass this structures from c++ to c# (later c++ to c++ cause will move to Linux).

What zeromq techniques should I use? As far as I understand I should:

- use PUB-SUB because i have one reader and one writer
- use `inproc` as a fasters transport (I understand limitations and OK to have them)
- use [zero-copy](https://zguide.zeromq.org/docs/chapter2/#Zero-Copy) to deliver my `OrderUpdate` structure to zeromq publisher buffer
- use ZMQ_DONTWAIT ?

Am I correct about that and probaly you can suggest more?

Comment: Have you tried it out? What happens?

Comment: after all i decided to pass pointer to structure, instead of zero-copy it :)